# How to avoid form submitting for button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two submit buttons and a few textboxes on my page. When I enter details in the textbox and hit the enter button the form should actuate the start new button. But the form is actuating the old button. I don't want to add `on click` to button because I am checking some conditions and redirecting from my controller. What do I have to do to avoid my form from actuating by default for old value button on hitting the enter button any suggestions, please?

controller :

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model, string new, string old)
{ 
    if (new == "new")
    {
        if (rows > 0)
        {
            return ProcessAction();
        }
        else
        {
            return ProcessAction();
        }
    }

    if (old == "old")
    {
        if (rowsAmount > 0)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

View:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Application", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col aligncenter">          
        <div class="form-row topMargin">               
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirsttName)                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-9 form-group text-right">
                <button class="btn" type="submit" name="old" value="old">Get History</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group text-right">
                <button class="btn" type="submit" name=newr" value="new">Start New</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to cange form submitting through `old button` just Change `button type` from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-9 form-group text-right">
        <button class="btn" type="btn" name="old" value="old">Get History</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group text-right">
        <button class="btn" type="submit" name=newr" value="new">Start New</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

> update

you can give `Get History button` a `click event` you can make an `Ajax call` through javascript `function` and give that to get history or bind your `controller action` in the anchor link and

Comment: because they don't have click event you need to give that a click event you can make a javascript function and give that to get histry or bind your controler in anchor link

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons have `type="submit"` which means they will submit the form when pressed. Instead use `type="button"` to avoid submitting the form. You can also use `type="reset"` if you want to provide a way to reset the form inputs.

```html
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <button type="button">Just a button</button>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset the form</button>
</form>
```